# Download .txt with Python that is accessed through an php request

Tags: php, python, browser, download, web-crawler

I'm trying to automatically download these ebooks:
http://www.getfreeebooks.com/?p=10394

Using url's like this the individual .txt files can be downloaded:
http://manybooks.net/_scripts/send.php?tid=lovecrafthother06At_the_Mountains_of_Madness&book=1:text:.txt:text

however the file can not be saved using for instance these lines:

```
url = "http://manybooks.net/_scripts/send.php?tid=lovecrafthother06At_the_Mountains_of_Madness&book=1:text:.txt:text"
testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve(url, "book 001.txt")
```

Probably because the file is accessed through php and I'm trying to download a php request. However I can't seem to find the right approach.

Thanks for looking into my problem! Jelle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not because the file is being accessed via php, it's because the server doesn't seem to like you using an empty User-agent.  Go ahead and let them know who you are!

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "jpostma1's crawler"
}

url = "http://manybooks.net/_scripts/send.php?tid=lovecrafthother06At_the_Mountains_of_Madness&book=1:text:.txt:text"
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
testfile = urllib2.urlopen(req)
with open("book 001.txt",'w') as w:
    w.write(testfile.read())
```